# Spring startup program cannot find the main class after adding Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-tool-suite

I runs as a Spring boot App in spring toolsuite. I add elasticsearch in pom.xml.
When i then tried to run the program as a spring boot app again, it threw the following error below.
"Error: Could not find or load main class com.spring.elastic.SpringBootDataElasticsearchApplication"
I use org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.0.1

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: did you run the application from the main class?

Comment: yes i tried, but it didn't work

Comment: can you post the error stack what you see in console ? Also check under your maven dependencies that spring-**-elasticsearch is actually present

Comment: This is all that the error stack what i see in console. Error: Could not find or load main class com.spring.elastic.SpringBootDataElasticsearchApplication

Comment: can you try this. I dont know why it is looking for version no.

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Comment: i try, but it reported an error in file pom.xml ." Failure to transfer org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.

Comment: Try using https://start.spring.io/ to create a simple project and import it into eclipse as an existing maven project. this is easiest way to create a Spring project. you can easily find videos on youtube to do this.